# How to validate XML variable against XSD in PostGreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, validation, xsd

I am trying to port an MS SQL script to execute in PostGreSQL. It uses an XML schema collection script that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [MySchema] AS N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
<xsd:element name="MyRootElement"> 
<xsd:complexType> <xsd:complexContent> <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType"> <xsd:sequence> <xsd:element name="Child1" minOccurs="0"> <xsd:complexType> <xsd:complexContent> <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType"> <xsd:sequence>
    .
    .
```

Can I convert this XML schema type for use in PostGreSQL? So I can use the definition for stored procedure xml-type input parameter validation. If not, how do I ensure that the input parameter has the required schema?

I read that [The xml type does not validate input values against a document type declaration (DTD), even when the input value specifies a DTD. There is also currently no built-in support for validating against other XML schema languages such as XML Schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-xml.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would write a custom function (in PL/Perl or PL/Python perhaps) that does the required validation, and hook that to the column using a check constraint.